# How to prevent an application from adding a scheduled task?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I use [Garena](http://intl.garena.com/) to play online. However, it has this annoying habit of adding a scheduled task on every startup in order to bypass UAC prompts. Basically, it keeps running its DLL (named **ggspawn.dll**) in the background to prevent UAC prompts.

Call me pedantic, but I don't like unwanted processes running in the background. Its my personal desktop and I have disabled UAC since ***I have full admin access***.

So how do I prevent specific applications from creating scheduled tasks?

I am using Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to "block the dll", then you have to block the executable for which it is associated.
Well, some firewalls can block .dll files, but would probably break the executable, they depend on running their libraries.

A solution to your problem could be to [disable the Task Scheduler](http://www.tricksguide.com/stop-task-scheduler-in-windows-7vista.html)

**NOTE**: It could cause problems disabling this, but i've also seen it be disabled without problems.

If I were you I would try disabling/removing the specified task associated with Garena, before doing the above.

Comment: Disable task scheduler? There are some existing tasks created by Windows itself. If I disable TS, will it cause problems with windows?

Comment: see my edit for more details :)

Comment: I tried disabling the same from TS as well as remove the startup entry. However, it adds the job again when I run Garena. Renaming the exe responsible causes Garena to spit errors. :(

Comment: Yea that is your problem. I think, if you want to use Garena, then you have to live with its functionalities. If I were you I would probably find some another program to use as this is not very reliable and puts your computer at unnecessary risk.

Comment: You're probably right. I don't seem to find any other alternative. Oh well..